# Dynamic routes in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My simplified setup is something like this:

- 2 AZs and each consists of 2 subnets (Subnet1-AZ-A, Subnet2-AZ-A, Subnet1-AZ-B, Subnet2-AZ-B)

I want to create routing table that will fetch CIDR blocks from Subnet1 (from both AZs) and create routes:

- CIDR_BLOCK of Subnet-1-AZ-A -> VPC_ENDPOINT in Subnet-2-AZ-A
- CIDR_BLOCK of Subnet 1-AZ-B -> VPC_ENDPOINT in Subnet-2-AZ-B

I don't want to hardcode values, because number of AZs (and subnets) may change.

Here's code that I'm using:

Subnet-1A

```
resource "aws_subnet" "Subnet1" {
  count = length(var.az)
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.app-vpc.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, 4+count.index)
  availability_zone = var.az[count.index]
  }
```

VPC_Endpoints:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "endpoint-spoke" {
  count = length(var.az)
  service_name      = var.glbe_service_name
  subnet_ids        = [aws_subnet.endpoint-subnet[count.index].id]
  vpc_endpoint_type = var.glbe_endpoint_type
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.app-vpc.id

}
```

Route-Table

```
resource "aws_route_table" "IGWRT" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app-vpc.id
  dynamic "route" {
    
    for_each = aws_subnet.Subnet1[*].cidr_block
    content {
      cidr_block      = route.value
      vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint-spoke[*].id
    }
  }
}
```

The code in Route-Table is not working. I know `aws_subnet.Subnet1[*].cidr_block` will be a list that contains Subnet1 CIDR blocks for example: [10.0.0.0/20, 10.0.1.0/24], but how I can create dynamic routes where:

- 10.0.0.0/0 will be pointing to VPC_Endpoint in respective AZ
- 10.0.0.1/0 will be pointing to VPC_Endpoint in respective AZ

Comment: Do you need one route table per subnet or one for all? could you give the example config for 3 AZs? because it wouldn't make sense to have two routes for the others subnets

Comment: Actutally I want only 1 route table, because I want to associate that RT with the IGW as Edge association.

Comment: So if you have 3 subnets, should `CIDR_BLOCK of Subnet-1-AZ-A` point to `VPC_ENDPOINT in Subnet-2-AZ-A` or `VPC_ENDPOINT in Subnet-3-AZ-A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the dynamic block in the `aws_route_table` resource:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "IGWRT" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.app-vpc.id
  
  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.Subnet1
    content {
      cidr_block      = route.value.cidr_block
      vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint-spoke[route.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

However, I strongly recommend you to use a `for_each` instead of the `count`, if the elements of the list change (the variable az), it will affect all of the resources as their index will be updated.

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem. Can you elaborate more how does [route.key] work?

Comment: It’s the key of the elements, in this case it refers to the index as the resources was created using count, so it’s translate to 0, 1 and 2.